# Don't get the ASCII codes for some keys

Tags: c++, winapi, ascii

I have been making a project and one of the thing this project does it uses the keys that are pressed on the keyboard. It reads the the ASCII code for each key, but some keys don't give away any signal for example: ' . ', ' / ', ' ; ' and so on...

```
char i;

while(1){
    for(i = 0; i <= 190; i++){
        if(GetAsyncKeyState(i) == -32767)
            key_pressed(i, "KEYS.TXT");
    }
}
```

This is how I monitor the keys.

Comment: Keyloggers are so last decade.

Comment: You probably don't want to use `==`. Use `GetAsyncKeyState(i) & 0x8001`. Nitpicking - using hexadecimal makes it more clear that you're checking bit flags.

Answer (score 3):

[`GetAsyncKeyState()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646293(v=vs.85).aspx) uses [virtual key codes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375731(v=vs.85).aspx), not ASCII values.
Some of these codes coincide with the ASCII values (e.g., `A` is 0x41 in both), but not all.

In this case, if you want to know if the `;` (or `:`) key was pressed, you would use `VK_OEM_1` (or 0xBA)

You might be able to use [`VkKeyScan()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646329(v=vs.85).aspx) to translate ASCII codes to virtual key codes. (I haven't tested it, so can't tell you if it will actually work)